# Unity Web Apps in New tab

Tags: unity, webapps

I have Youtube intergrated into Unity Laucher as a webapp.  But when I open it, it opens in a new window instead of opening in the existing browser window.  How do I enable opening as a new tab instead of a new window?

Thanks!

Comment: Well for one that's the point of having it as a Web App and not just as a bookmark in your browser. So it works as a standalone app.